# Node not sending object properties to mongo db

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a program that accepts an image and creates a string that links to the image to save in the database.
currently I have the string stored in a state called `image1`
And I am sending the data to my backend with the following code on the front end

```
const scheduleEvent = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let userData = [
    {
      image: image1
    },
  ];
  axios.post(
    "proper-url",
    userData
    
  );
  console.log(userData) // this returns: 0: {image: "https://i.imgur.com/LnZUdnr.jpg"}
};
```

And I this is my webhook to capture the data and send it to the database

```
exports = async function(payload, response) {
  if (payload.body) {
      const body =  EJSON.parse(payload.body.text());
      const customerEvents= context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("db").collection("events");
      const event = {
           
    image: body.image1,
    
          
      };
  
      return await customerEvents.insertOne(event);
  }
  return  {}
};
```

However my database entries look like this `_id:6229194de167780bd1982029` without the image variable. I know that my code is connecting to the database and adding things to it, but no matter what I do I cannot get it to record the `image1` string

Answer (score 1):

In your client code you're sending a field named `image`, but in your server side you're looking for the field `image1`. This is undefined, which is why it's not showing up in your database.

Comment: I've been tinkering with this, so should I change `image` to `image1` on the client side, webhook, or both?

Comment: I have changed the client side and server side to both be `image1` and the issue persists. I've also changed all variables to simply `image` and the data is still not sending

Comment: At this point, I would suggest console.log-ing your body variable after parsing it - see what you're actually getting. If the field's missing at all, I'd double check the object you're actually sending from the client. It's probably missing data.